# Working of thermometer and mercury

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, metals

If mercury is a poor conductor of heat, then how does it work in a thermometer?

Comment: "poor" relative to what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mercury (as most of metals) exapnds with heat. So, this expansions means a raise of the height of the column, what we measure in the thermometer

Comment: *The difference* in the coefficients of the thermal expansion of mercury and the glass container is important, in mercury it  is higher.

Answer (score 2):

The thermal conductivity of the mercury determines how fast the mercury temperature equilibrates with the temperature of the medium it is measuring, not what the value of the temperature it indicates is once it gets there.  Since the volume of mercury in the thermometer is relatively small, and the surface to volume ratio of the mercury is relatively large (i.e., the linear dimensions of the mercury are small), the response time for the mercury to thermally equilibrate is relatively rapid.

Answer (score 0):

Although the thermal conductivity of mercury is just under 50 times less than that of copper it is about 20 times a better conductor than glass of which the bulb is probably made.

As the majority of the initial expansion will occur in the mercury which is in the bulb and convection will also aid the heat transfer process mercury is satisfactory for use as the liquid in a thermometer.

Then what other liquid might one use?
The thermal conductivities of water and alcohol are much lower than that of mercury.

What would be the thermal capacity (heat require to raise the temperature by one degree) of the liquid in the bulb.
Here the important parameter is the density times the specific heat capacity if you want to compare bulbs of equal volume.
For mercury and alcohol the product of density and specific heat capacity is approximately the same because although mercury has a very high density it is almost exactly compensated by having a relatively low specific heat capacity.

So these are some of the reasons which make mercury a satisfactory liquid for use in a thermometer.